# Discrete time Fourier transform of an exponential decaying sigal

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dtft

I have a fundamental question about the discrete-time Fourier transform. I used two methods but got two results.

### Background knowledge

The discrete time signal is given by:
$$x[ n ] = x[ {n{T_s}} ] = x( t )\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {\delta ( {t - n{T_s}} )} = x(t)\delta_s(t)$$ where $T_s=\frac{1}{f_s}$

The definition of the discrete signal might be different in some books (with or without $T_s$).

1. I know that the transform is given by:
   $${X_{d1}}(f) = \sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {{x_T}[n]{e^{ - j2\pi nf{T_0}}}}$$
2. I also know that the discrete signal can be regarded as the product of two signals, thus the Fourier transform will be the convolution of these two signals:

$$\begin{gathered}
  {X_d}( f ) = X( f) * {\Delta _s}( f ) = X( f ) * \sum\limits_{m =  - \infty }^\infty  {{f_s}\delta ( {f - m{f_s}} )}  \\ 
         = \sum\limits_{m =  - \infty }^\infty  {{f_s}X( {f - m{f_s}})}  \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

$\space\space\space\space$ where $X(f)$ is the Fourier transform of the continuous signal $x(t)$, and $\Delta_s(f)$ corresponds to $\delta_s(t)$.

The Fourier transform of the delta train is also a delta train, which can be found elsewhere.

This equation gives that if we know the Fourier transform of a continuous signal, then the transform of its discrete signal will be given by the summation of its ***scaled*** and ***shifted*** version.

### An example

Based on the above two statements, I can calculate the Fourier transform of the following signal:
$$x(t) = {e^{ - 5t}}u(t) \xrightarrow{{{T_s} = 0.1}}x[ n ] = {e^{ - 0.5n}}u[ n ]$$

1. Based on the first 'theorem':

$${X_{d1}}(f) = \sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {{x}[n]{e^{ - j2\pi nf{T_s}}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{e^{ - (0.5 + j0.2\pi )n}}}  = \frac{1}{{1 - {e^{ - 0.5 - j0.2\pi f}}}}$$

2. Based on the second 'theorem':
   $$\begin{gathered}
     \because x( t )\overset F \longleftrightarrow X( f ) = \frac{1}{{5 + j2\pi f}} \hfill \\
     \therefore {X_{d2}}( f ) = \sum\limits_{m =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{10}}{{5 + j2\pi (f - 10m)}}}  \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered} $$

***Not so apparently, but $X_{d1}$ and $X_{d2}$ are different. Just check the value when $f=0$.***

Below are the plots, which show that there is a shift between the two methods. So what's wrong there?

***I would greatly appreciate any discussion about this.***

The reference book is :
https://www.amazon.nl/-/en/Gordon-Carlson/dp/0471124656

[image: DTFT results]

The code:

```matlab
%define the frequency axis
f=-30:0.001:30;

% the spectrum of the continuous signal
%the continuous signal is $x(t)=e^{-5t}$
Xf = 1./(5+1j*2*pi*f);

%The discrete time signal is sampled when $T_s=0.1$
Ts=0.1;
Fs=1/Ts;

%calculate the spectrum based on definition 
Xdf1 = zeros(1,numel(f),'like',1j);
for mm=0:100
Xf1 = exp(-(0.5+1j*0.2*pi*f)*mm);
Xdf1 = Xdf1 + Xf1;
end

%calculate the summation of the shifted and scaled spectrum 
Xdf2 = zeros(1,numel(f),'like',1j);
for mm=-40:40
Xf1 = Fs./(5+1j*2*pi*(f-Fs*mm));
Xdf2 = Xdf2 + Xf1;
end


%plot
figure
plot(f,abs(Xf));grid on
hold on;
plot(f,abs(Xdf1));grid on
hold on;
plot(f,abs(Xdf2));
legend('X(f)','Xd1','Xd2');
xlabel('freqeuncy [Hz]');ylabel('Amplitude')
```

Comment: Hay, your post ***looks*** very pretty in how you put in .png pics for your equations.  But what I recommend in the future is that you use $\LaTeX$ to express equations.  It makes it easier for people answering your question because we can just copy the equation and modify it easily in our answer.  Also, I recommend the O&S style of notation for discrete-time (and discrete-frequency) functions.  So it should be $$ x[n] \triangleq x(nT_\mathrm{s}) $$ where $T_\mathrm{s} = \frac{1}{f_\mathrm{s}}$.  Brackets for integer arguments of discrete-time functions and parenths for continuous-time.

Comment: [Related discussion](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88571/63398)

Comment: Perfectly explained in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88571/68888.  Thanks Ahsan